# Gray line shows in some IE 8 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I would really appreciate some help here. I am trying to remove a gray line from the top navigation, which shows up in some IE 8 browsers. For some weird reason, my client sees a gray line in front of an horizontal menu text in IE 8 and I don't see that line in my IE 8. It is so hard to debug when you don't see it in front of you. Does any one have any ideas?

Here is link to the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODSSS.jpg

Notice the gray line left of Member Organization??? Every time you resize the browser, the gray line moves across the top navigation too. So weird...

Here is my top nav CSS code:

```
.top-nav{width:825px; float:right; clear:both; margin:0 0 10px 0;z-index:1!important;}
ul#horizontal-nav,ul#horizontal-nav ul{margin:0;list-style:none;background-color:#ffffff;}
ul#horizontal-nav ul {display:none;position:absolute;left:0;top:100%;padding:0;background-color:#ffffff; border-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px;}
ul#horizontal-nav li:hover>*{display:block; }
ul#horizontal-nav li:hover{position:relative;}
ul#horizontal-nav ul ul{position:absolute;left:100%;top:0;}
ul#horizontal-nav{padding:0;display:block;font-size:0;float:left;}
ul#horizontal-nav li{display:block;white-space:nowrap;font-size:0;float:left;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#6699cc;border-radius:10px;-moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px;}
ul#horizontal-nav>li,ul#horizontal-nav li{margin:0 0 0 6px;}
ul#horizontal-nav a:active, ul#horizontal-nav a:focus{outline-style:none;}
ul#horizontal-nav a{display:block;vertical-align:middle;text-align:left;text-decoration:none;font-size: 12px; font-family:"Arial", serif, sans-serif;color:#666666;padding:2px 24px;background-color:#ffffff;background-repeat:repeat;border-width:0;border-style:solid;border-color:transparent; }
ul#horizontal-nav ul li{float:none;margin:0;}
ul#horizontal-nav ul a{text-align:left; border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#6699cc; border-top:none; border-bottom:1px solid #666666;}
ul#horizontal-nav li:hover>a{font-size: 12px; font-family:"Arial", serif, sans-serif;color:#0066cc;text-decoration:none;}
ul#horizontal-nav li ul li{border:none;  width:156px;}
ul#horizontal-nav li ul {z-index:1;}
ul#horizontal-nav img{border:none;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:8px;}
ul#horizontal-nav img.over{display:none;}
ul#horizontal-nav li:hover > a img.def{display:none;}
ul#horizontal-nav li.topmenu>a{height:20px;background-color:#ffffff;border-radius:15px;-moz-border-radius:10px;-webkit-border-radius:10px;font-size: 12px; font-family:"Arial", serif, sans-serif;color:#666666;text-decoration:none;line-height:19px;background: url("../images/topNav-arrow-off.gif") no-repeat; background-position:6% 45%; margin-left:10px;}
ul#horizontal-nav li.topmenu:hover>a{font-size: 12px; font-family:"Arial", serif, sans-serif;color:#666666;text-decoration:none;line-height:19px;background: url("../images/topNav-arrow-on.gif") no-repeat; background-position:left 45%;}
ul#horizontal-nav li.subfirst>a{border-top:1px solid #6699cc; border-radius:9px 9px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:9px 9px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:9px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0;}
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<div class="top-nav">
     <ul id="horizontal-nav" class="topmenu">
          <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
               <ul>
                <li class="subfirst"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                   <li class="sublast"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
                    </li>
              <li class="topmenu"><a href="web/secondary-page.html">Link 3</a></li>
              <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              <li class="topmenu"><a href="#">Link 5</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="subfirst"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li class="sublast"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Try to get a screenshot from him/her.

Comment: I do have a screenshot, but I am trying to figure out why is he seeing it in his IE 8 and I am not on mine.

Comment: "It is so hard to debug when you don't see it in front of you." - couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YUtMN/

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot?

Comment: Yes, screenshot would be nice but without that lucky guesses.... Check font size of the browser perhaps or if the site is security zone is something else, trusted, intranet etc?

Comment: I tried on IE8, it's fine, for me.

Comment: wow.. you guys are super fast. Thanks again. How do I post images here. It says I need 10 reputations to post images????

Comment: @Sue: [Upload it here](http://imgur.com/), and edit the link to the uploaded image into the question.

Comment: alright here is the link.. http://i.imgur.com/ODSSS.jpg

Comment: hi guys... any ideas???? I uploaded the image.

Comment: @Sue: Looking at the screenshot, I see the line you're talking about. However, I still don't have enough information to give you a good answer. To help resolve that, could you post a link to your site? If you *really* don't want to make it public, you could email me a link (see my profile). Emailing one user a link to the site isn't the Stack Overflow way, but it looks like I'm the only person showing any interest here, so I guess it's alright in this case.